# How to upload Bitmap Image from a android device?

Tags: java, android, http, multipartform-data

Thank you in advance.
I'd like to upload some bitmap image from my android app.
but , I can't get it.
Could you recommend some solutions for it.
or collect my source code?

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://example.com/imagestore/post");
                MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity( HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE );
                byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
                try {
                    entity.addPart("img", new StringBody(new String(bao.toByteArray())));
                    httppost.setEntity(entity);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = null;
                try {
                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? What technology are you using at the server side? Are you sure the problem isn't there and not in the client?

Comment: Thank you for replying. So I've developed the servicede on GAE, the GAE said raise NotImageError(); I guess the String Encoding is wrong or have to use InputStreamBody

Comment: I got my goal Using InputStream with file name "img.jpg" . :-)

Comment: would you mind sharing how you coded in the InputStream implementation?

Answer (score 3):

use httpmime for uploading Image 
try this  
http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/

Comment: The tutorial you referenced uses MultipartEntity which is deprecated now. Maybe you should edit your answer, so people could know.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution really well created and 100% working even with amazon ec2, take a look into this link:

[**Uploading files to HTTP server using POST on Android (link deleted).**](http://stunningco.de/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/)

Compare to previous answer, this solution **doesn't require** to import huge library `httpmime` from Apache.

Copied text from original article:

This tutorial shows a simple way of uploading data (images, MP3s, text files etc.) to HTTP/PHP server using Android SDK.

It includes all the code needed to make the uploading work on the Android side, as well as a simple server side code in PHP to handle the uploading of the file and saving it. Moreover, it also gives you information on how to handle the basic autorization when uploading the file.

When testing it on emulator remember to add your test file to Android’s file system via DDMS or command line.

What we are going to do is set the appropriate content type of the request and include the byte array as the body of the post. The byte array will contain the contents of a file we want to send to the server.

Below you will find a useful code snippet that performs the uploading operation. The code includes also server response handling.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
DataInputStream inputStream = null;
String pathToOurFile = "/data/file_to_send.mp3";
String urlServer = "http://192.168.1.1/handle_upload.php";
String lineEnd = "\r\n";
String twoHyphens = "--";
String boundary =  "*****";

int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
byte[] buffer;
int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

try
{
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile) );

    URL url = new URL(urlServer);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    // Allow Inputs &amp; Outputs.
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);

    // Set HTTP method to POST.
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

    outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\"" + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    // Read file
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    while (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

    // Responses from the server (code and message)
    serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

    fileInputStream.close();
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Exception handling
}
```

If you need to authenticate your user with a username and password while uploading the file, the code snippet below shows how to add it. All you have to do is set the Authorization headers when the connection is created.

```
String usernamePassword = yourUsername + “:” + yourPassword;
String encodedUsernamePassword = Base64.encodeToString(usernamePassword.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
connection.setRequestProperty (“Authorization”, “Basic ” + encodedUsernamePassword);
```

Let’s say that a PHP script is responsible for receiving data on the server side. Sample of such a PHP script could look like this:

```
<?php
$target_path  = "./";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) 
{
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
 " has been uploaded";
} 
else
{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>;
```

Code was tested on Android 2.1 and 4.3. Remember to add permissions to your script on server side. Otherwise, the uploading won’t work.

```
chmod 777 uploadsfolder
```

Where uploadsfolder is the folder where the files are uploaded. If you plan to upload files bigger than default 2MB file size limit. You will have to modify the upload_max_filesize value in the php.ini file.

Comment: It seems the post in the link mentioned is no longer available :(

Comment: @SeverianoJaramilloQuintanar brought text from the deleted link